# Echo new row when it got added to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying for a few days now to figure out how I can do this.
I have two pages, one is `index.php`, other is `add.php .`

1)Index.php - I want it do display last 5 rows from database table.

2)Add.php - contains form which adds new row to database.

**How can I update values that are shown on index.php when I add new row?**

So lets say I have index.php already opened on one tab, and on other one is Add.php. When I fill the form on add.php,

I want it to automatically notifies index.php that there is a new row,and that it should change values without refreshing the index.php tab.

*Do I need VPS for this?What is the best way to do this theoretically?*

Comment: A VPS? *Virtual Private Server*? What does that have anything to do with this? You've also said you've tried for a few days now. Where are your attempts? What have you tried?

Comment: ' trying for a few days now to **figure out how** I can'
I am asking a question because I have no clue how I can make this work.

Comment: You either need to use websockets to push out an event to the `Index.php` page when a new row gets added to the database, or use some type of polling/refresh using AJAX or simply refreshing the page at set intervals.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in setting up a VPS for this. A VPS is Just a server in which u can install your own software. You are already using a server for PHP (local perhaps).

U can create a websocket server. Once you add a row you send a message tot the websocket server which will then tell the index page to resfresh.

Previous option is a lot of work for a rather simple functionaliteit. I'd suggest the simplest option as recommended by FrankerZ. Only if you refresh the page at a set interval using JavaScript (window.setInterval) then the page would keep refreshing. I don' t think that's ideal. You van however send a xhtmlhttprequest to store the contents for the index page and run that request every x seconds. Then u can compare the 2 contents and decide if the page should be refreshed or not.

Comment: I have managed to do it by setting setInterval with Javascript which sends ajax request ever 5 seconds,in which I get latest rows and with the response I replace existing values.Websocket is something that I will 100% look into. Thank you both for suggestions :)